# Data extraction from source with lots of white space

Tags: csv, screen-scraping, text-processing

I'm trying to extract data from : http://www.phillysheriff.com/old_site/properties.html

Ideally I'd be able to get a CSV file with the address, ward, price, and square feet? Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The process of extracting information like this from webpages is known colloquially as "scraping". If it was me I'd use the python language and the ["Beautiful Soup"](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) package to do it. However, a google for "screen scrape" or "web scrape" and your favourite programming language should find you a package that will do the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can run IRobotSoft web scraper, open the page in its browser window, and use menu: Design -> Practice HTQL.  Give the following HTQL query in the input box to transform the page into a standard HTML table:

```
<hr sep>2-0{
a=<center>1 &tx &trim;
b=<center>1:xx ./'nbsp'/1 &tx &trim('&; ');
c=<center>1:xx ./'nbsp'/3 ./'\n'/1 &tx &trim('&; ');
d=<center>1:xx ./'nbsp'/3 ./'Ward'~'BRT#'/1 &tx;
e=<center>1:xx ./'nbsp'/3 ./'BRT#'~'Improvements:'/1 &tx;
f=<center>1:xx ./'nbsp'/3 ./'Improvements:'/2 &tx;
g=<br sep>2. /'nbsp'/1 &tx &trim('&; ');
h=<br sep>2. /'nbsp'/3 &tx &trim('&; '); 
i=<br sep>2. /'nbsp'/5 &tx &trim('&; ');
j=<br sep>2. /'nbsp'/7 &tx &trim('&; ');
}
```